# New Extended Classes Without A Separate File For Each One

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class, called Building, and there are several classes that extend it, for example, Office and Hospital. The extending classes add at most, only a dozen or so lines of code, thus I would not like to put them in different files. I don't believe inner classes will work since it requires an instance of the outer class first -> Building.

Thus, what I want to do is do `Building b = new Office(var);`, but not have Office code in Office.java since it will contain at most  a few lines of code, but Building will have most of the code. But having Office as the type is valuable in my situation. Any help? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Best advice? Put it in separate files.

Comment: In that case you want to go with something other than java.  That's part of the language Spec, I believe.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, in java only 1 public class may be declared per file

Comment: Putting the classes into separate files is probably the best advice but if in case you're _really_ resisting that, what about static inner classes? They don't require any outer instance, e.g. you could do `Building b = new Building.Office()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a static nested class, then you wouldn't need an instance of Building, but I think in this case the best thing would be to use separate Java files. It doesn't matter if they only contain a few lines.

Comment: Are there any precautions I should be wary that this change may introduce?

Comment: Terminology: an inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static.

Comment: what change? putting them in different files or using static nested classes?

Comment: Not really that I'm currently aware of, but either creating a new object or importing the class is a bit more awkward, as you have to prepend "Building."

Comment: Thanks. Accepted since first.

Answer (score 0):

> . I don't believe inner classes will work since it requires an instance of the outer class first -> Building.

You can make them `static` nested classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static nested class:

```
public class Building {

    public static class Office extemds Building {
    }
}
```

You can then create an Office like this:

```
Office o = new Building.Office();
```

But you should probably put them in individual files to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can define it as a static inner class, but I fail to see the point, because it makes the class more cumbersome to use. Just because a class is small doesn't mean it shouldn't be in its own file.

```
public class Building {
    ...
    public static class Office extends Building {
        ...
    }
}

Building.Office office = new Building.Office();
```